# How can a town capture a Fomorian?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I am running an arena based campaign, and want to pit my party against a Fomorian. The only problem I am running into is how the town would have gone about capturing a Fomorian and disabling it long enough to put it in the arena.

Once the fight starts, the Fomorian will focus on the party because its life is being threatened, but I don't know how to get it to that point.

Comment: If the town is Las Vegas ... the same way it captures us puny humans. ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to depend on the oldest of DM methods: hand-waving.

"We traded four children -- they were nothing but trouble anyway -- for this creature and the key to the charm that restrains it.  We didn't ask the name of the trader; didn't really want to know.  But that doesn't matter.  What matters to you is that you're going to have to fight it.  Tonight."

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this, but thank you. That answers my question.

Comment: You can even get less slave trade if you want. Something like they are by a mine or somewhere you think a fomorian could be close. "We dug in the mine, found this thing and it chased us. We lured it into a massive cage that was built a long time ago for some war against giants."

Comment: Thank you. I am probably going to emphasize slave trade, since I know that my players dislike the notion and I want to drive them to try and do something about it.

Answer (score 4):

The problematic abilities are **Evil Eye** and **Curse of the Evil Eye**. Luckily we have the following.

> **Evil Eye:** The fomorian magically forces a creature **it can see**
>
> **Curse of the Evil Eye (Recharges after a Short or Long Rest).** With a stare, the fomorian uses Evil Eye,

So a hunting party goes out and overpowers a fomorian, the first thing they will do after it is incapacitated is put a iron hood over it's head that blinds the formorian.

The only way to make it safe for public spectacles is either blind it and train it to blind fight. Or for the formorian fight make sure crowd is more than 60 feet from the formorian. Perhaps by dragging out or erecting a large cage in the middle of the arena. The formorian likely will be wheeled in hooded and immoblie. The mechanism would have a long chain or a enclosed room with a lever so somebody in the arena can release the Formorian from the restraints and the hood for the fight.

Either way it going to have to be setup so that that arena operators earn their investment because all this will be very expensive to implement. It would be far cheaper to capture a giant, disfigure it  and call it a fomorian rather trying to deal with a real one.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the classics: *Gulliver's Travel*. In there, a single giant is captured by a bunch of tiny people while he is sleeping.

This will do two things for you.

- Show the PCs that the villagers are not damsels in distress waiting for adventurers to do something
- Present the PCs with ideas for overcoming other/future challenges.